# Dining Philosopher Thread and Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, dining-philosopher

I made a simple GUI that has 5 tables and forks and tried to visualize this famous problem, but I cannot achieve to fully implement. I didn't get the stuck point for my code, if anyone have suggestion for me to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!
Extra Note: There is also an error that i guess it is about my array creation ideas, i have an error as java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5.

```
public class Philosopher implements Runnable {


    private static Table table;
    private int ID;
    private int N = 5;
    private static Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore(1) ;
    private static Semaphore[] sarray = new Semaphore[5];
    private int[] array = new int[5];
    private int thinking = 0;
    private int hungry = 1;
    private int eating = 2;
    private int left = (ID + N - 1) % N;
    private int right = (ID + 1) % N;

    void test(int i)
    {
        if((array[i] == hungry) && (array[left] != eating) && (array[right] != eating))
        {
            table.ForkTake_GUI(i);
            array[i] = eating;
            sarray[i].release();

        }   
    }

    void take_forks(int i)
    {
        try {
            s1.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        array[i] = hungry;
        table.Hungry_GUI(i);
        test(i);
        s1.release();
        table.Eating_GUI(i);
        sarray[i].release();
    }

    void put_forks(int i)
    {
        table.StopEating_GUI(i);
        try {
            s1.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        array[i] = thinking;
        test(left);
        test(right);
        table.ForkPut_GUI(i);
        s1.release();

    }

    public Philosopher(int i)
    {
        setID(i);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Random RandomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomNum = RandomGenerator.nextInt(10);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((randomNum * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            take_forks(ID);
            //table.Eating_GUI();
            put_forks(ID);      
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    table = new Table();
                    table.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        Philosopher p1 = new Philosopher(1);
        Philosopher p2 = new Philosopher(2);
        Philosopher p3 = new Philosopher(3);
        Philosopher p4 = new Philosopher(4);
        Philosopher p5 = new Philosopher(5);
        Thread pt1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread pt2 = new Thread(p2);
        Thread pt3 = new Thread(p3);
        Thread pt4 = new Thread(p4);
        Thread pt5 = new Thread(p5);

        sarray[0] = new Semaphore(1);
        sarray[1] = new Semaphore(1);
        sarray[2] = new Semaphore(1);
        sarray[3] = new Semaphore(1);
        sarray[4] = new Semaphore(1);

        pt1.start();
        pt2.start();
        pt3.start();
        pt4.start();
        pt5.start();

    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I didn't get the stuck point for my code"*  If you're not stuck, why are you here? *"if anyone have suggestion for me to solve this problem"*  I still do not even know what your problem is.

Comment: I dont know why my code is running properly, this is my stuck point, i stuck somewhere but i don't know, this was my attemtp to explain and tell

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? This looks like correct solution (safe, starvation free), but only one philosopher can eat at a time.

Comment: Yes, exactly but for the final solution, i must conclude that two philosopher can eat at the same time and the other three might be hungry or at the process of thinking.

Comment: I have also an error as java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at where you acquire a mutex from `sarray` - point is that you don't, so at least there's redundant code in there.

Further notes:

- You define N but use the magic number 5 all over.
- You seem to have one "central" mutex and one for each fork. Using a central mutex would already solve the original problem.
- Consider putting each mutex and the data it protects into an aggregate. That would make it clear that the five mutexes are for the five forks and not for the five philosophers, or?
- Your out-of-bounds is obviously caused by a shift between 1-base and 0-based indices. Could that be caused by changing ID after computing left and right? In general, I wouldn't store these as members. Also, be aware that the values you have there are for the philosophers, not for the forks! Draw a picture, that will help you get those right!